# Somehow I updated my module version and it show belows error

Tags: ionic-framework

Somehow I updated my module version and it shows below error :

```
 Type Login in F:/ionic/PkjshopCourier/src/pages/login/login.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules:
  AppModule in F:/ionic/PkjshopCourier/src/app/app.module.ts and LoginModule in
               F:/ionic/PkjshopCourier/src/pages/login/login.module.ts! Please consider moving Login in
               F:/ionic/PkjshopCourier/src/pages/login/login.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in
               F:/ionic/PkjshopCourier/src/app/app.module.ts and LoginModule in
               F:/ionic/PkjshopCourier/src/pages/login/login.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is shown in the output... you have login.ts declared in two places. app.module.t and login.module.ts.

You probably want to remove it from app.module.ts